# Efficient Way to Replace Unicode Hex Character Codes in Snowflake String

Tags: javascript, python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I currently have an issue where text I am importing includes Unicode Hex Character Codes in item descriptions.

For example,   may appear for a no-break space, ê may appear for the French language "ê", etc.

I am wanting the text returned in a view to show the actual characters, rather than the hex character codes.

The best solution I have found so far involves doing something like the below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ENTITY_TO_SYMBOL(STRING VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS 
$$
  return STRING.replace(/&Agrave;/g, "À").replace(/&Aacute;/g, "Á").replace(/&Acirc;/g, "Â").replace(/&Atilde;/g, "Ã").replace(/&Auml;/g, "Ä").replace(/&Aring;/g, "Å").replace(/&agrave;/g, "à").replace(/&acirc;/g, "â").replace(/&atilde;/g, "ã").replace(/&auml;/g, "ä").replace(/&aring;/g, "å").replace(/&AElig;/g, "Æ").replace(/&aelig;/g, "æ").replace(/&szlig;/g, "ß").replace(/&Ccedil;/g, "Ç").replace(/&ccedil;/g, "ç").replace(/&Egrave;/g, "È").replace(/&Eacute;/g, "É").replace(/&Ecirc;/g, "Ê").replace(/&Euml;/g, "Ë").replace(/&egrave;/g, "è").replace(/&eacute;/g, "é").replace(/&ecirc;/g, "ê").replace(/&euml;/g, "ë").replace(/&#131;/g, "ƒ").replace(/&Igrave;/g, "Ì").replace(/&Iacute;/g, "Í").replace(/&Icirc;/g, "Î").replace(/&Iuml;/g, "Ï").replace(/&igrave;/g, "ì").replace(/&iacute;/g, "í").replace(/&icirc;/g, "î").replace(/&iuml;/g, "ï").replace(/&Ntilde;/g, "Ñ").replace(/&ntilde;/g, "ñ").replace(/&Ograve;/g, "Ò").replace(/&Oacute;/g, "Ó").replace(/&Ocirc;/g, "Ô").replace(/&Otilde;/g, "Õ").replace(/&Ouml;/g, "Ö").replace(/&ograve;/g, "ò").replace(/&oacute;/g, "ó").replace(/&ocirc;/g, "ô").replace(/&otilde;/g, "õ").replace(/&ouml;/g, "ö").replace(/&Oslash;/g, "Ø").replace(/&oslash;/g, "ø").replace(/&#140;/g, "Œ").replace(/&#156;/g, "œ").replace(/&#138;/g, "Š").replace(/&#154;/g, "š").replace(/&Ugrave;/g, "Ù").replace(/&Uacute;/g, "Ú").replace(/&Ucirc;/g, "Û").replace(/&Uuml;/g, "Ü").replace(/&ugrave;/g, "ù").replace(/&uacute;/g, "ú").replace(/&ucirc;/g, "û").replace(/&uuml;/g, "ü").replace(/&#181;/g, "µ").replace(/&#215;/g, "×").replace(/&Yacute;/g, "Ý").replace(/&#159;/g, "Ÿ").replace(/&yacute;/g, "ý").replace(/&yuml;/g, "ÿ").replace(/&#176;/g, "°").replace(/&#134;/g, "†").replace(/&#135;/g, "‡").replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&gt;/g, ">").replace(/&#177;/g, "±").replace(/&#171;/g, "«").replace(/&#187;/g, "»").replace(/&#191;/g, "¿").replace(/&#161;/g, "¡").replace(/&#183;/g, "·").replace(/&#149;/g, "•").replace(/&#153;/g, "™").replace(/&copy;/g, "©").replace(/&reg;/g, "®").replace(/&#167;/g, "§").replace(/&#182;/g, "¶").replace(/&Alpha;/g, "Α").replace(/&Beta;/g, "Β").replace(/&Gamma;/g, "Γ").replace(/&Delta;/g, "Δ").replace(/&Epsilon;/g, "Ε").replace(/&Zeta;/g, "Ζ").replace(/&Eta;/g, "Η").replace(/&Theta;/g, "Θ").replace(/&Iota;/g, "Ι").replace(/&Kappa;/g, "Κ").replace(/&Lambda;/g, "Λ").replace(/&Mu;/g, "Μ").replace(/&Nu;/g, "Ν").replace(/&Xi;/g, "Ξ").replace(/&Omicron;/g, "Ο").replace(/&Pi;/g, "Π").replace(/&Rho;/g, "Ρ").replace(/&Sigma;/g, "Σ").replace(/&Tau;/g, "Τ").replace(/&Upsilon;/g, "Υ").replace(/&Phi;/g, "Φ").replace(/&Chi;/g, "Χ").replace(/&Psi;/g, "Ψ").replace(/&Omega;/g, "Ω").replace(/&alpha;/g, "α").replace(/&beta;/g, "β").replace(/&gamma;/g, "γ").replace(/&delta;/g, "δ").replace(/&epsilon;/g, "ε").replace(/&zeta;/g, "ζ").replace(/&eta;/g, "η").replace(/&theta;/g, "θ").replace(/&iota;/g, "ι").replace(/&kappa;/g, "κ").replace(/&lambda;/g, "λ").replace(/&mu;/g, "μ").replace(/&nu;/g, "ν").replace(/&xi;/g, "ξ").replace(/&omicron;/g, "ο").replace(/&piρ;/g, "ρ").replace(/&rho;/g, "ς").replace(/&sigmaf;/g, "ς").replace(/&sigma;/g, "σ").replace(/&tau;/g, "τ").replace(/&phi;/g, "φ").replace(/&chi;/g, "χ").replace(/&psi;/g, "ψ").replace(/&omega;/g, "ω").replace(/&bull;/g, "•").replace(/&hellip;/g, "…").replace(/&prime;/g, "′").replace(/&Prime;/g, "″").replace(/&oline;/g, "‾").replace(/&frasl;/g, "⁄").replace(/&weierp;/g, "℘").replace(/&image;/g, "ℑ").replace(/&real;/g, "ℜ").replace(/&trade;/g, "™").replace(/&alefsym;/g, "ℵ").replace(/&larr;/g, "←").replace(/&uarr;/g, "↑").replace(/&rarr;/g, "→").replace(/&darr;/g, "↓").replace(/&barr;/g, "↔").replace(/&crarr;/g, "↵").replace(/&lArr;/g, "⇐").replace(/&uArr;/g, "⇑").replace(/&rArr;/g, "⇒").replace(/&dArr;/g, "⇓").replace(/&hArr;/g, "⇔").replace(/&forall;/g, "∀").replace(/&part;/g, "∂").replace(/&exist;/g, "∃").replace(/&empty;/g, "∅").replace(/&nabla;/g, "∇").replace(/&isin;/g, "∈").replace(/&notin;/g, "∉").replace(/&ni;/g, "∋").replace(/&prod;/g, "∏").replace(/&sum;/g, "∑").replace(/&minus;/g, "−").replace(/&lowast;/g, "∗").replace(/&radic;/g, "√").replace(/&prop;/g, "∝").replace(/&infin;/g, "∞").replace(/&OEig;/g, "Œ").replace(/&oelig;/g, "œ").replace(/&Yuml;/g, "Ÿ").replace(/&spades;/g, "♠").replace(/&clubs;/g, "♣").replace(/&hearts;/g, "♥").replace(/&diams;/g, "♦").replace(/&thetasym;/g, "ϑ").replace(/&upsih;/g, "ϒ").replace(/&piv;/g, "ϖ").replace(/&Scaron;/g, "Š").replace(/&scaron;/g, "š").replace(/&ang;/g, "∠").replace(/&and;/g, "∧").replace(/&or;/g, "∨").replace(/&cap;/g, "∩").replace(/&cup;/g, "∪").replace(/&int;/g, "∫").replace(/&there4;/g, "∴").replace(/&sim;/g, "∼").replace(/&cong;/g, "≅").replace(/&asymp;/g, "≈").replace(/&ne;/g, "≠").replace(/&equiv;/g, "≡").replace(/&le;/g, "≤").replace(/&ge;/g, "≥").replace(/&sub;/g, "⊂").replace(/&sup;/g, "⊃").replace(/&nsub;/g, "⊄").replace(/&sube;/g, "⊆").replace(/&supe;/g, "⊇").replace(/&oplus;/g, "⊕").replace(/&otimes;/g, "⊗").replace(/&perp;/g, "⊥").replace(/&sdot;/g, "⋅").replace(/&lcell;/g, "⌈").replace(/&rcell;/g, "⌉").replace(/&lfloor;/g, "⌊").replace(/&rfloor;/g, "⌋").replace(/&lang;/g, "⟨").replace(/&rang;/g, "⟩").replace(/&loz;/g, "◊").replace(/&#039;/g, "'").replace(/&amp;/g, "&").replace(/&quot;/g, "\"").replace(/&#xe9;/g,"é").replace(/&apos;/g,"'").replace(/&#xea;/g,"ê").replace(/&#xe0;/g,"à").replace(/&#xa0;/g," ").replace(/&#xb0;/g,"°").replace(.replace(/&#xb1;/g,"±");
$$;
```

This is obviously a nightmare to read, and in order for it to truly be inclusive I would likely need to write a script to generate all the replaces needed.

While I could do this, it does not necessarily seem like the most efficient way to essentially manually replace each character.

I had seen on a different site someone recommending using a lookup table to do this. I could figure out how to do something like this in Python, but was not sure if there was an easy approach for this in Snowflake.

The idea would be having a table where one column is the code, another is the value, and then the UDF would basically replace all instances of any codes with their corresponding values.

This seems like it would be a common problem, but I have not come across any specific solutions.

Any advice regarding how to do this and whether it would be best practice would be appreciated. I know ideally we would parse before loading, but due to the nature of our platform I need to do these transformations in Snowflake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with a Python UDF:

```sql
create or replace function py_unescape(X string)
returns string
language python
handler = 'x'
runtime_version = 3.8
as $$
import html

def x(s):
    return html.unescape(s)
$$
;

select py_unescape('&Agrave; makes me feel &Aacute;');
-- À makes me feel Á
```